# How to show that $\left| \frac{-x^2y-y^3-y}{x^2+y^2} \right| < \pi$?

Tags: analysis, inequality, proof-writing

How to show that

$$\left| \frac{-x^2y-y^3-y}{x^2+y^2} \right| < \pi$$

if $1<\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}<4$?

Attempt: My work shows it is false. What is wrong about the solution?
$$ \frac{1}{4} \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$$
$$ \Rightarrow -1 \leq -(x^2 + y^2) \leq -\frac{1}{4} $$
$$ \Rightarrow -2 \leq -(x^2 + y^2) - 1 \leq -\frac{5}{4} $$
$$\Rightarrow 0 \leq \left|-(x^2+y^2)-1\right|\leq 2$$

Also, since $x^2\ge0$ and $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$, we get $0\leq|y|\leq1$.

Thus,
$$\left|-(x^2+y^2)-1\right|\cdot|y|\leq 2 \cdot1\Rightarrow\left|\left[-(x^2+y^2)-1\right]y\right|=\left|-x^2y-y^3-y\right|\leq 2$$

Furthermore,
$$\frac{1}{4} \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \Rightarrow 1 \leq \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \leq 4$$

Also, $1/(x^2+y^2) \geq 0$, so $1/(x^2+y^2) = |1/(x^2+y^2)|$

Therefore

$$\left|\frac{-x^2 y - y^3 - y}{x^2 + y^2}\right|= \left|-x^2y-y^3-y\right|\cdot\left|\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq 2\cdot4 = 8 < \pi$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please show your work and give some context.

Comment: Hi my post is edited

Comment: It has already been asked few days ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4537905/505767)

Comment: They are slightly different

Comment: Showing that $A<8$ does **not** mean that $A<\pi$ is false. Take $A=1$ for example. Then obviously $A<8$, but also clearly $A<\pi$. It just tells you that your bounds are not good enough to show what you want to show, and you need to improve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so we want to show that

$$\left\lvert \frac{-x^2y-y^3-y}{x^2+y^2} \right\rvert < \pi$$

whenever

$$1<\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}<4.$$

Now notice that then

$$\left\lvert \frac{-x^2y-y^3-y}{x^2+y^2} \right\rvert= \frac{x^2+y^2+1}{x^2+y^2}\lvert y\rvert\leq\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}<3<\pi,$$

and so we are done.

The problem with your solution is that you don't actually show anything else than that the quantity is smaller than $8$, which is certainly true but not very useful. This does not mean that it is not also smaller than $\pi$. The reason you end up in such a situation is because you estimate things separately, leading to very rough, and ultimately bad, bound.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that by bounding separately the two expression and then putting them togheter we are not able to obtain a "good" estimation for the upper bound.

For example consider for $0<x<1$

- $0<1-x^2<1$
- $\frac34<1-\left(x-\frac12\right)^2<1$

then

$$\left(1-x^2\right)\left(1-\left(x-\frac12\right)^2\right)\le\frac{225}{256}<1$$

---

For the solution, as indicated in the linked very similar question, by polar coordinates with $\frac12<r<1$ we obtain

$$\left| \frac{-x^2y-y^3-y}{x^2+y^2} \right|=\left|\frac{-r^3\sin \theta-r\sin \theta}{r^2}\right| =|\sin \theta|\cdot \frac{1+r^2}{r}<\frac1r+r<\frac 5 2<\pi$$

Note that $|\sin \theta|=1$ when $x=0$ that is

$$\left| \frac{-x^2y-y^3-y}{x^2+y^2} \right|=\left| \frac{-y^3-y}{y^2} \right|=\left| y+\frac1y \right|<\frac52$$